# RMarkdown PDF: ! Misplaced \noalign

Tags: r, kableextra

This is my dataset:

```
structure(list(grp = c("Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", 
"Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Catalunya", "Espanya", 
"Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", "Espanya", 
"Zona euro", "Zona euro", "Zona euro"), ...1 = c("Població activa", 
"Població ocupada", "Població en atur", "Taxa d'ocupació (16-64 anys, %)", 
"Taxa d'atur (%)", "Afiliació a la Seguretat Social", "Atur registrat", 
"Població activa", "Població ocupada", "Població en atur", 
"Taxa d'ocupació (16-64 anys, %)", "Taxa d'atur (%)", "Afiliació a la Seguretat Social", 
"Atur registrat", "Ocupació", "Taxa d'ocupació (15-64 anys, %)", 
"Taxa d'atur (%)"), `2020` = c(-1.26839233534172, -3.04809376067197, 
13.0847696095673, 67.0925, 12.635, -2.56184474168086, 21.1826104693573, 
-1.27577940774132, -2.91655923111536, 8.71827635843001, 61.9475, 
15.5325, -2.19941425385114, 17.8188983021421, 1, 66.85, 7.875
), `2021` = c(1.94340042691949, 3.18739133041548, -6.67185069984448, 
68.9625, 11.565, 2.65857732877581, -5.2563187744479, 2.06678961392581, 
2.97449410686412, -2.87106069939181, 63.795, 14.785, 2.70215065508972, 
-3.89736496774028, -1.7, 67.875, 7.725), `2022` = c(-0.0301881944890559, 
2.09681519410247, -16.2861745264678, 70.225, 9.685, 3.83887864972354, 
-18.876581280129, 0.913452577071894, 3.12019561435448, -11.8084005190185, 
65.505, 12.9175, 3.79262159563356, -16.8978292575669, 1, 69.4, 
6.775), `1r 2023` = c(1.99922108269506, 1.85115552598849, 3.29781836631151, 
69.4, 10.37, 3.02181041714329, -5.7146162870376, 1.38051712425944, 
1.83273835307471, -1.47730494219925, 65.2, 13.26, 2.61666709067936, 
-7.08354716233971, 1.91225710479803, 69.5, 6.8), `2n 2023` = c(2.81592167976299, 
3.77733598409542, -6.57420249653259, 71.91, 8.44, 2.94860134018895, 
-4.39319912524291, 1.84629330323165, 2.87619699042407, -5.37439199835583, 
66.99, 11.6, 2.69191266607034, -6.90855143327568, 1.49541299041116, 
70.3, 6.3), `3r 2023` = c(3.4827138162085, 4.39619090423888, 
-5.42168674698795, 72.5, 8.5, 2.76585066636925, -3.91667160303214, 
2.52955253571594, 3.50535635193738, -4.19434937252533, 67.34, 
11.84, 2.85840068444791, -7.3934987898817, NA, NA, NA), `ag. 2023` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.79186387198558, -3.44014019290773, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 2.84156691399289, -7.57598555522119, NA, NA, NA), 
    `set. 2023` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.70204800089409, -5.33024006683261, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.72703019423044, -7.4594507870543, NA, 
    NA, NA), `oct. 2023` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.61365216182399, 
    -2.38594696490765, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.55953296962417, 
    -5.33426281316769, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the table I am doing in RMarkdown:

```
p4_2 <- read_xlsx("G:/SUBDIRECCIO-ESTUDIS/CONJUNTURA/INDICADORS MENSUALS/Automatitzacio_IC/proves R/IC_fitxer_RECULL_Maria.xlsx",
                  range = "B19:M39", 2, col_types = c("text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")) [, -c(5,9)] 
#importem des de la línia dels anys

options(knitr.kable.NA = "-")

grp_nm <- c("Catalunya", "Espanya", "Zona euro")

p4_2 <- 
  p4_2 %>% 
  mutate(grp = ifelse(...1 %in% grp_nm, ...1, NA))%>%
  fill(grp) %>% 
  filter(!...1 %in% grp_nm) %>% 
  select(grp, everything())
  

kable(p4_2[, -1],
      align = "lrrrrrrrrr",
      col.names = c("", names(p4_2[-(1:2)])),
      booktabs=TRUE,
      digits=1,
      format.args = list(big.mark="."),
      caption="\\textbf{Comerç exterior} (\\% de variació interanual)", escape = FALSE,
      vline = "",
      toprule = "\\arrayrulecolor{black}\\toprule",
      bottomrule = "\\arrayrulecolor{orange}\\bottomrule[1.1pt]",
      linesep = "\\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\\midrule[0.5pt]") %>%
  add_header_above(c("", "Any" = 3, "Trimestre" = 3, "Mes" = 3), bold=T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options=c("HOLD_position","scale_down"), position="center") %>% 
  column_spec(1, width="6cm") %>% 
  column_spec(2:10, width="1cm") %>% 
  row_spec(0, bold = T) %>% 
  pack_rows(index = table(p4_2$grp), background = "#E0E0E0", latex_gap_space = "0.5pt")
```

When I knit it to PDF, I get the following error:

> ! Misplaced \noalign. \midrule ->\noalign
> {\ifnum 0=`}\fi @aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global @... l.321 \end{tabular}}
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile provaM.tex. See
> https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
> provaM.log for more info. Execution halted

And I don't understand where this error is coming from, as I am using the same code for other tables...

This is my Tex file:

```
\begin{table}[H]

\caption{\label{tab:taula_4_2}\textbf{Comerç exterior} (\% de variació interanual)}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\arrayrulecolor{black}\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Any}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Trimestre}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Mes}} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-4} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){5-7} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){8-10}
\textbf{} & \textbf{2020} & \textbf{2021} & \textbf{2022} & \textbf{1r 2023} & \textbf{2n 2023} & \textbf{3r 2023} & \textbf{ag. 2023} & \textbf{set. 2023} & \textbf{oct. 2023}\\
\midrule
\addlinespace[0pt]
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E0E0E0}{\textbf{Catalunya}}}\\
\hspace{1em}Població activa & -1,3 & 1,9 & 0,0 & 2,0 & 2,8 & 3,5 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Població ocupada & -3,0 & 3,2 & 2,1 & 1,9 & 3,8 & 4,4 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Població en atur & 13,1 & -6,7 & -16,3 & 3,3 & -6,6 & -5,4 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Taxa d'ocupació (16-64 anys, %) & 67,1 & 69,0 & 70,2 & 69,4 & 71,9 & 72,5 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Taxa d'atur (%) & 12,6 & 11,6 & 9,7 & 10,4 & 8,4 & 8,5 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Afiliació a la Seguretat Social & -2,6 & 2,7 & 3,8 & 3,0 & 2,9 & 2,8 & 2,8 & 3,7 & 2,6\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Atur registrat & 21,2 & -5,3 & -18,9 & -5,7 & -4,4 & -3,9 & -3,4 & -5,3 & -2,4\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\addlinespace[0pt]
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E0E0E0}{\textbf{Espanya}}}\\
\hspace{1em}Població activa & -1,3 & 2,1 & 0,9 & 1,4 & 1,8 & 2,5 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Població ocupada & -2,9 & 3,0 & 3,1 & 1,8 & 2,9 & 3,5 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Població en atur & 8,7 & -2,9 & -11,8 & -1,5 & -5,4 & -4,2 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Taxa d'ocupació (16-64 anys, %) & 61,9 & 63,8 & 65,5 & 65,2 & 67,0 & 67,3 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Taxa d'atur (%) & 15,5 & 14,8 & 12,9 & 13,3 & 11,6 & 11,8 & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Afiliació a la Seguretat Social & -2,2 & 2,7 & 3,8 & 2,6 & 2,7 & 2,9 & 2,8 & 3,7 & 2,6\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Atur registrat & 17,8 & -3,9 & -16,9 & -7,1 & -6,9 & -7,4 & -7,6 & -7,5 & -5,3\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\addlinespace[0pt]
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E0E0E0}{\textbf{Zona euro}}}\\
\hspace{1em}Ocupació & 1,0 & -1,7 & 1,0 & 1,9 & 1,5 & - & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Taxa d'ocupació (15-64 anys, %) & 66,8 & 67,9 & 69,4 & 69,5 & 70,3 & - & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\hspace{1em}Taxa d'atur (%) & 7,9 & 7,7 & 6,8 & 6,8 & 6,3 & - & - & - & -\\
\arrayrulecolor{orange}\bottomrule[1.1pt]
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Session info:

```
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Catalan_Spain.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Catalan_Spain.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Catalan_Spain.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Catalan_Spain.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] float_0.3-2        extrafont_0.19     tinytex_0.49       formattable_0.2.1  stargazer_5.2.3    kableExtra_1.3.4   data.table_1.14.10 forcats_1.0.0      tibble_3.2.1       ggplot2_3.4.4      tidyverse_2.0.0    knitr_1.45         zoo_1.8-12        
[14] httr_1.4.7         rvest_1.0.3        lubridate_1.9.3    fs_1.6.3           readxl_1.4.3       readr_2.1.4        stringr_1.5.1      purrr_1.0.2        tidyr_1.3.0        dplyr_1.1.4        openxlsx_4.2.5.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.11       svglite_2.1.3     lattice_0.22-5    digest_0.6.33     utf8_1.2.4        R6_2.5.1          cellranger_1.1.0  evaluate_0.23     pillar_1.9.0      rlang_1.1.1       rematch_2.0.0     curl_5.2.0        rstudioapi_0.15.0
[14] jquerylib_0.1.4   extrafontdb_1.0   rmarkdown_2.25    webshot_0.5.5     selectr_0.4-2     htmlwidgets_1.6.4 munsell_0.5.0     compiler_4.2.3    xfun_0.41         pkgconfig_2.0.3   systemfonts_1.0.5 htmltools_0.5.7   tidyselect_1.2.0 
[27] fansi_1.0.6       viridisLite_0.4.2 tzdb_0.4.0        withr_2.5.2       grid_4.2.3        jsonlite_1.8.8    Rttf2pt1_1.3.12   gtable_0.3.4      lifecycle_1.0.4   magrittr_2.0.3    scales_1.3.0      zip_2.3.0         cachem_1.0.8     
[40] cli_3.6.1         stringi_1.8.3     bslib_0.6.1       xml2_1.3.6        generics_0.1.3    vctrs_0.6.5       tools_4.2.3       glue_1.6.2        hms_1.1.3         fastmap_1.1.1     yaml_2.3.8        timechange_0.2.0  colorspace_2.1-0 
[53] sass_0.4.8       
> sessioninfo::session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  Catalan_Spain.utf8
 ctype    Catalan_Spain.utf8
 tz       Europe/Paris
 date     2023-12-20
 rstudio  2023.03.0+386 Cherry Blossom (desktop)
 pandoc   2.19.2 @ C:/Users/45647016C/AppData/Local/Programs/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 bslib         0.6.1   2023-11-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 cachem        1.0.8   2023-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 cli           3.6.1   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 colorspace    2.1-0   2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 curl          5.2.0   2023-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 data.table  * 1.14.10 2023-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 digest        0.6.33  2023-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 dplyr       * 1.1.4   2023-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 evaluate      0.23    2023-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 extrafont   * 0.19    2023-01-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 extrafontdb   1.0     2012-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fansi         1.0.6   2023-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 float       * 0.3-2   2023-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 forcats     * 1.0.0   2023-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 formattable * 0.2.1   2021-01-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fs          * 1.6.3   2023-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 generics      0.1.3   2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 ggplot2     * 3.4.4   2023-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 gtable        0.3.4   2023-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 hms           1.1.3   2023-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 htmltools     0.5.7   2023-11-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 htmlwidgets   1.6.4   2023-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 httr        * 1.4.7   2023-08-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 jquerylib     0.1.4   2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 jsonlite      1.8.8   2023-12-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 kableExtra  * 1.3.4   2021-02-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 knitr       * 1.45    2023-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 lattice       0.22-5  2023-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 lifecycle     1.0.4   2023-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 lubridate   * 1.9.3   2023-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 openxlsx    * 4.2.5.2 2023-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pillar        1.9.0   2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 purrr       * 1.0.2   2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Rcpp          1.0.11  2023-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 readr       * 2.1.4   2023-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 readxl      * 1.4.3   2023-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rematch       2.0.0   2023-08-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rlang         1.1.1   2023-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rmarkdown     2.25    2023-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rstudioapi    0.15.0  2023-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Rttf2pt1      1.3.12  2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rvest       * 1.0.3   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 sass          0.4.8   2023-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 scales        1.3.0   2023-11-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 selectr       0.4-2   2019-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 stargazer   * 5.2.3   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 stringi       1.8.3   2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 stringr     * 1.5.1   2023-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 svglite       2.1.3   2023-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 systemfonts   1.0.5   2023-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tibble      * 3.2.1   2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tidyr       * 1.3.0   2023-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tidyselect    1.2.0   2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tidyverse   * 2.0.0   2023-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 timechange    0.2.0   2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tinytex     * 0.49    2023-12-13 [1] Github (yihui/tinytex@3136eef)
 tzdb          0.4.0   2023-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 utf8          1.2.4   2023-10-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 vctrs         0.6.5   2023-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 viridisLite   0.4.2   2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 webshot       0.5.5   2023-06-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 withr         2.5.2   2023-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 xfun          0.41    2023-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 xml2          1.3.6   2023-12-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 yaml          2.3.8   2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 zip           2.3.0   2023-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 zoo         * 1.8-12  2023-04-13 [1] CRAN
```

(R 4.2.3)

Comment: It looks like you have some unescaped `%` symbols in the generated LaTeX. If you try manually escaping those, can you compile the .tex file?

If escaping them in the generated .tex works, you can then go back and escape them (perhaps with a `gsub()`?) as part of your R code

Comment: What is included in the yaml header? The data and code works fine with the latest R studio on a windows PC with the relevant packages. With the dataset the question does not need to have `grp_nm` and the data wrangling for `p4_2`.

Comment: This is what's included in the yaml header:  \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage{floatrow} 
    \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
    \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

Comment: The code workd fine, yes, but when I knit it to PDF then I get the error \misalign

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in my set up. The Rmarkdown code produces a pdf with some warnings but no error.

Comment: Is it something with my RStudio version? Or RMarkdown?

Comment: Could be ... what versions are they? Perhaps [edit] your question and add the output from `sessionInfo()` or `sessioninfo::session_info()` to a [code block].

Comment: ok I've just added this output

Comment: `kableExtra` has recently had a lot of bug fixes, though they aren't on CRAN yet.  You could install the current patched version with `remotes::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")` and see if that makes a difference.